# Doctrine query with a condition on number of relationships

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities: `Location` and `Program`. They have a many-to-many relationship. A program has the attribute `$status`, which can be `'published'` or `'unpublished'`.

Now I wish to run a query (with the doctrine query builder) to return all of my `Location` entities which have a relationship with at least 10 `Program` entities with the `$status` being `'published'`.

**My code so far**

```
    public function findLocationsOfPublishedPrograms()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->innerJoin('l.programs', 'p')
        ->andWhere('p.status = \'published\'')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $qb;
}
```

This query retuns all `Location` entities that have at least *one* published program. But is there any way I could set a condition to only return `Location` entities which have at least *10* published programs?

Comment: Do not completely sure, but query should look DQL like `select l,count(p) as c from Location l join Program p with p.status=:status group by l.id having c>=10`

Comment: There is also [`size()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) function in Doctrine, maybe it will help somehow

Comment: @Flying, I am going to have a look. Thank you so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could innerJoin WITH p.status = published. Then addWhere with a count of p.* >= 10

Examples of innerJoin with conditions are in the docs: 
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder

Comment: `count()` is an aggregate, your query needs to contain at least `group by` clause